# How to retrieve all properties of an Ember.js model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working with forms in Ember.js and I want to retrieve a list of all model properties so that I can take snapshots of the state of the form at different moments. Is there a way to get a list of all properties of a model?

For example, if my model is:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  current_password: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  password_confirmation: DS.attr('string'),
  admin: DS.attr('boolean'),
}
```

Then I would like to have something like this:

```
> getEmberProps('User')

["name", "email", "current_password", "password", "password_confirmation", "admin"]
```

Comment: JSON.stringify? Have you tried that?

Comment: hmmm, I wouldn't know how to JSON.stringify that to an Ember model

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply use [toJSON](http://ember-doc.com/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON) method on model and get the keys from object.

```
Ember.keys(model.toJSON())
```

Note that will not return you keys for relations.

Comment: `Note that will not return you keys for relations` -> I don't know which ember version you are using; I am using Ember 1.11.3 at the moment, for that version relations keys are returned as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use this:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_attributes
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_eachAttribute

```
Ember.get(App.User, 'attributes').map(function(name) { return name; });
Ember.get(userInstance.constructor, 'attributes').map(function(name) { return name; });
```

There's also similar properties for relationships too.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to print out the fields and their values:

```
Ember.keys(model.toJSON()).forEach(function(prop) { console.log(prop + " " + model.get(prop)); } )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, but you could try a custom mixin like this:

```
Ember.AllKeysMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    getKeys: function() {
        var v, ret = [];
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                v = this[key];
                if (v === 'toString') {
                    continue;
                } // ignore useless items
                if (Ember.typeOf(v) === 'function') {
                    continue;
                }
                ret.push(key);
            }
        }
        return ret
    }
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
App.YourObject = Ember.Object.extend(Ember.AllKeysMixin, {
 ... //your stuff
});
var yourObject = App.YourObject.create({
  foo : "fooValue";
});
var keys = yourObject.getKeys(); // should be ["foo"];
```

Comment: Thanks @mavilein What I don't like of this solution is having to use a mixin. I've come up myself with something that seems to work (see my edit). Could your solution work without having to extend from a mixin?

Comment: If you don't like in the mixin, it should be easy to extract the code into a separate function with the model as the argument. But i don't understand, why you don't like the mixin. This is probably the most emberish way to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm getting confused but if I use the mixin in this way, what I get is the properties of the object instance but I can't do that: `User = DS.Model.extend(Ember.AllKeysMixin,{
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  current_password: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  password_confirmation: DS.attr('string'),
  admin: DS.attr('boolean'),` and then `model.getKeys()`somewhere else to get 'name', 'email', etc..

Comment: Ah, i did not understand your question that way. So you want to get the properties of the class and not those of the instance. When i read model, i am always thinking about the instance. So my approach won't work. Maybe one could migrate this function relatively easy to the class by adding it so a class via reopenClass()..

Comment: Maybe the title of my question is misleading. If someone can think of a better title I will be happy to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

in 2018: use Ember Data's [eachAttribute](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.Model/methods/eachAttribute?anchor=eachAttribute).

So, given a model Foo:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    "name": attr('string'),
    "status": attr('string')
});
```

Let's get the model's definition via the constructor:

```
var record = this.store.createRecord('foo', {
    name: "model1",
    status: "status1"
});
this.modelClass = record.constructor;
```

and invoke a function for each of its Ember Data attributes:

```
modelClass.eachAttribute(function(key, meta){ 
   //meta provides useful information about the attribute type
}
```